# Leetcode 28 Question - Why is my strStr() failing?

Tags: python, string, substring

I am attempting to solve this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/127/strings/885/

The idea is that you write code that can find a substring within a string. For the sake of practice, I am (or atleast was) trying to do this in the most efficient way possible. I figured it can be done in one "for" loop (hopefully only taking O(n) time)

This is my code

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        needle = list(needle)
        haystack = list(haystack)
        goodPos = None
        goodCounter = 0
        if len(needle) == 0:
            return 0
        if len(haystack) == 0 or len(needle) > len(haystack):
            return -1
        for key, value in enumerate(haystack):
            if needle[goodCounter] != value:
                print(f"{needle[goodCounter]} does not match {value}, resetting")
                goodPos = None
                goodCounter = 0
            if needle[goodCounter] == value:
                print(f"We have a match at {value}")
                if goodCounter == 0:
                    print(f"We are setting the key at {key}")
                    goodPos = key
                goodCounter += 1
            if len(needle) == goodCounter:
                return goodPos
        print("Finished for loop")
        print(f"goodPos at {goodPos}")
        print(f"goodCounter at {goodCounter}")
        #For situations where we didnt caught it
        if goodCounter == len(haystack):
            return len(haystack)
        return -1
```

I am stuck on 73 / 79 test cases passed. Specifically with this input

```
Input: "mississippi" (substring: "issip")
My output: -1
Expected Output: 4
```

I am kind of stuck why my code is not working.

Comment: What steps have you take to try to debug this code yourself?

Comment: A lot of commenting, I feel like the code gets stuck because it resets in between the valid string. For reference, this is output from the "print" statements: https://pastebin.com/611UnC6s . I am not sure if the correct solution is to use a double forloop but that means it would take O(n^2)

Comment: Yeah, I'd start with the naive solution: for each position in the haystack, check to see if needle is a substring at that position. The complexity won't be O(N^2), it'll be O(MN), where M is the length of the haystack and N is the length of the needle.

Comment: you need a way to go back in the `haystack` as well, with the `for` loop, you just keep moving ahead and so don't match the words that have been traversed before. It would be ideal to use a `while` loop here to only move the characters in the `haystack` one by one. with the above approach, once you have iterated over `missis` part of `haystring`, there is no way to use `is` again for building `issippi`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get when I run your code:

```
key,value,goodPos,goodCounter
0  ,m    ,None   ,0
1  ,i    ,None   ,0
2  ,s    ,1      ,1
3  ,s    ,1      ,2
4  ,i    ,1      ,3
5  ,s    ,1      ,4
6  ,s    ,None   ,0
7  ,i    ,None   ,0
8  ,p    ,7      ,1
9  ,p    ,None   ,0
10 ,i    ,None   ,0
```

They key keeps getting incremented and by the time it realizes that keyPos = 1 is not a complete match, the key has already been set to position 7 and by then it's too late to find a match. I think you need a nested for loop.

Edit:

I decided to take a stab at it myself and here's the for loop I came up with:

```py
    for key, value in enumerate(haystack):
        if needle[0] == value:
            goodPos = key
            for key, value in enumerate(needle):
                if (len(haystack) - goodPos) < len(needle):
                    print('Needle went past end of haystack. No match found')
                    return -1
                if value == haystack[goodPos + key]:
                    goodCounter += 1
                    if len(needle) == goodCounter:
                        print('Match found at goodPos = ', goodPos)
                        return goodPos
                else:
                    goodCounter = 0
        else:
            goodPos = ''
            goodCounter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        result = -1
        try :
            result = haystack.index(needle)
        except:
            result = -1
        return result
```

Comment: Though this might address the question, please consider textually enriching your answer.

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32194221)